# How to determine if a date falls on the weekend?

Tags: vba, excel

Given a date as input, how can I determine whether the day falls on a weekend?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is a Weekday function that takes a Date as an argument and returns the day (1, 2, 3, etc.)

The return values are:

```
vbSunday (1)  
vbMonday (2)  
vbTuesday (3)  
vbWednesday (4)  
vbThursday (5)  
vbFriday (6)  
vbSaturday (7)
```

Assuming that weekends are Saturday and Sunday, the function would look like this:

```
Public Function IsWeekend(InputDate As Date) As Boolean
    Select Case Weekday(InputDate)
        Case vbSaturday, vbSunday
            IsWeekend = True
        Case Else
            IsWeekend = False
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Example of usage, as this was not made clear in the post: `IsWeekend("11/13/2017")`

Answer (score 16):

This is the most direct way to determine if `MyDate` falls on the weekend:

```
MsgBox Weekday(MyDate, vbMonday) > 5
```

The Weekday() function has an optional 2nd parameter that tells it which day of the week the week starts on. The Weekday() function returns an integer from 1 through 7.

I've instructed it to start the week on MONDAY and so SATURDAY would be 6 and SUNDAY would be 7.

Answer (score 7):

Or, you can use this:

```
OR(MOD(WEEKDAY(cell), 7)=0, MOD(WEEKDAY(cell), 7)=1)
```

or

```
MOD(WEEKDAY(cell), 7) < 2
```

as a formula.

since 1 is Sunday and 0 is Saturday

Answer (score 2):

Formula for converting date to week days

Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(WEEKDAY(R7C" + CStr(i) + ",1),""ddd"")"

this will return day

eg:-
if input is 02-may-2013 
then it will return Thu --> (thursday)
here variable i represents another column