# Calculating Business Minutes form 2 dates excluding weekends

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following code which calculates business minutes from 2 dates given. Where 9am is the start time and 5.30pm is finish time. However, how can I also incorporate a rule where I can prevent weekend hours being included? I am having such a mind block here :/

```
Function ElapsedBusinessMinutes(StartDateTime As Date, StopDateTime As Date) As Single
Dim dteAdjStart As Date
Dim lngElapsedMinutes As Long
Dim lngMinutesInWorkDay As Long
lngMinutesInWorkDay = 510
dteAdjStart = TimeValue(StartDateTime)
If dteAdjStart > #5:30:00 PM# Then
  dteAdjStart = TimeSerial(7, Minute(StartDateTime), Second(StartDateTime))
  lngElapsedMinutes = DateDiff("d", StartDateTime, StopDateTime - 1) * lngMinutesInWorkDay
Else
  lngElapsedMinutes = DateDiff("d", StartDateTime, StopDateTime) * lngMinutesInWorkDay
End If
ElapsedBusinessMinutes = lngElapsedMinutes + DateDiff("n", dteAdjStart, TimeValue(StopDateTime))
End Function
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine if a date falls on the weekend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580432/how-to-determine-if-a-date-falls-on-the-weekend)

Comment: The other thing to consider is that will the start/end date themselves ever be on the weekend? And to remove weekends, you can use loop each day from start to stop and use `WEEKDAY` function to determine if it's a weekend and exclude or not.